# Chinese fonts rendering slowly at certain sizes?

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, windows-ce, text-rendering, chinese-locale

This is going to sound ridiculous, but if I'm going to find someone who has even the foggiest clue about this, StackOverflow will be the place.

First, the platform I'm developing on: Motorola Handscanners. Running Windows CE 5 and/or 6. Running a web app on the mobile version of Internet Explorer 5.5. (I know, I know, but keep reading). Specifically the MC3190, MC9090 and MC3090. The 3090 has 64MB of ram, and the other two have 128.

Are you cringing? You should be. Read on anyways, it only gets more fun.

We made an update. Increased a font size slightly, and changed it's colour from black to blue. Wild, I know. All of our tests showed no issues at all, everyone loved the change, and it even seemed to increase user efficiency (industrial application).

Then we rolled it out to China, where the MC3090 is still used, with a Chinese installation of the OS with Chinese fonts. Immediately, rendering of text slowed to a crawl. We're talking 4 seconds to load an 8kb webpage. Networking is fine, the page is downloaded, but rendering seems to reach a standstill- and that is *killing* user efficiency. Also, it's pretty annoying for our users.

Potential solutions:

- Upgrade hardware (in the works, but potentially years away, and expensive)
- Don't make this change (considered, but we want to have our cake and eat it too)
- Quit my job, because IE 5.5 (I look at it like working with special needs children)

So I come to you StackOverflow to ask: Does anyone have a clue why a slight font change on Chinese Fonts could result in such a huge change in rendering time on IE 5.5 and Windows CE 5?

Comment: Share your markup, especially the part where you set the target font. It sounds like IE is being forced to use Font Fallback to hunt for a font containing the target characters; that can be slow.

Comment: This question made my day, thanks.

Comment: EricLaw: A year later, but I think you actually hit the nail on the head. We've got a backlog item from last year to do some more extensive testing on which font sizes render quickly or slowly, but some basic sanity tests show that certain font sizes are bad, and certain ones are good.